# How do I set the same attributes for multiple AutoCompleteTextViews?

Tags: android

Given that I have the following AutoCompleteTextViews

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter121 = new ArrayAdapter<String>    
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,androidBooks);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView0 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks1);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et3);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView2 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et4);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView3 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et5);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView4 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et6);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView5 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et7);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView6 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et8);
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView7 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et9);
```

How would I call:

```
    acTextView.setThreshold(1);
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter121);
```

on each of my AutoCompleteTextViews?

Comment: how acTextView0  and acTextView1 and acTextView2 will start in a code as like as acTextView.setThreshold(1);
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter121);

Comment: Update your post with your actual question. Simply posting code is not a valid question.

Comment: Are you asking how to set `.setThreshold(1)` and `.setAdapter(adapter121)`on each of your AutoCompleteTextViews?

Comment: yes MrEngineer13, pls help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain **in English**, possibly supplemented with screenshots, of what you want your app to do. p.s. Learn how to use arrays.

Comment: how to set .setThreshold(1) and .setAdapter(adapter121)on each of my AutoCompleteTextViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set each of the `AutoCompleteTextViews` you can add them an array `mAutoCompleteTextViews` and set the attributes by cycling through each one.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter121 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,androidBooks);

        AutoCompleteTextView[] mAutoCompleteTextViews = new AutoCompleteTextView[{
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks1),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et3),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et4),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et5),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et6),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et7),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et8),
        (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.et9)}];

        // for each loop to set parameters on each AutoCompleteTextView in mAutoCompleteTextViews 
        for (AutoCompleteTextView acTextView : mAutoCompleteTextViews ){
            acTextView.setThreshold(1);
            acTextView.setAdapter(adapter121);
        }
```

If you want to learn about arrays in Java then check out [this section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Arrays) from the Java wikibook

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a loop that does all of this for you

```
int numberOfViews = 9;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++){
    AutoComplete acTextView;
    if(i == 0)
        acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks);
    if(i == 1)
        acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AndroidBooks1);
    else{
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("et" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());
        acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(id);
    }
    acTextView.setThreshold(1);
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter121);
}
```